# Prevent opened window from overriding `close` method of opener

Tags: javascript, window

I have a `test1.html` file with only this code:

```
<script>
janela = window.open("http://localhost/test2.html","_blank","width=1000,height=400,left=600,top=0");
</script>
```

The code above will open the window `test2.html` which has this code:

```
<script>
opener.window.janela.close = null;
</script>
```

Now, on window `test1.html` if I try to close the window that I just opened using `janela.close()` I wont be able to do so.

I am aware that using `noopener` in the `window.open` method would block `test2.html` from acessing `test1.html` HOWEVER it also blocks me, at `test1.html` from closing `test2.html`.

So how can I reliably open a `window` and be able to confidently close it in the future?

**EDIT ACCORDING TO @mplungjan**

After the kind help of @mplungjan, I did this:

```
myClose = window.close;
janela = window.open("https://a2eestrutural.eng.br/?fdfk","_blank","width=1000,height=400,left=600,top=20");
janela.myClose = window.myClose;
```

After the window opened, I tried executing `janela.myClose();` and I got this error message:

```
An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

Any idea how can I continue from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have that code at all? If you have control over what is opened...

In any case try this before the script that opens the window

```
const myClose = window.close;
const janela = window.open("http://localhost/test2.html","_blank","width=1000,height=400,left=600,top=0");
....
janela.myClose()
```

OR

```
const myClose = window.close;
const janela = window.open("http://localhost/test2.html","_blank","width=1000,height=400,left=600,top=0");
janela.myClose = myClose;
....
janela.myClose()
```

You may VERY LIKELY get access errors or other errors since you are messing with the UX security-wise

Comment: I did exactly what you said and got the error `test1.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: janela.myClose is not a function`. I used this code: `<script>
const myClose = window.close;

janela = window.open("http://localhost/test2.html","_blank","width=1000,height=400,left=600,top=0");

window.setTimeout(function() {

 janela.myClose();

},1000);
</script>`

Comment: And if you do jamela.myClose =window.myClose; just after window.open?

Comment: Dear friend, I followed your instruction and I decided to edit my question so you can see the formated code better. I didnt paste it here in the comments because it would become ugly.

Comment: I then think you are SOL.

Comment: So it worked afterall?

Comment: No, it didnt work. I had to abandon the idea :( But I approved your answer since you lost time replying

Comment: Appreciated, but Please remove the tick so I can delete the answer